# Update one field from the currently loaded record

Tags: c#, datatable

Working in VS2010 / C# - I have a form that shows data by using tableadaptor (ie from the drag & drop)

One of the fields in my database is `booking`.`status`. I have NOT displayed that field on the form.

The form takes variable bookingId and uses it to load a single record using the FillBy method.

The code for the save button is

```
                this.bookingBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.bookingTableAdapter.Update(this.quick_quoteDataSet.booking);
```

Before this code executes, I would like to set the value of the `status` field to 'P'.

I can use this.bookingTableAdapter.Update() - but it seems I will have to read all of the values from the form and pass them into the update command along with the new value for the status field.

Is there a way I can simply amend the value of that one field for the current record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Stored Procedure

```
USE [Assets]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateAssDispRecord]    Script Date: 12/15/2012 08:00:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateAssDispRecord]

    @iDispID int,
    @nDispno decimal,
    @cKeygroup nchar(14),
    @iCodeID int,
    @dDate date,
    @nSale decimal,
    @nCumdep decimal,
    @nBookvalue decimal,
    @cRemarks nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
            UPDATE ass_Disp
            SET 
                nDispno=@nDispno,
                cKeygroup=@cKeygroup,
                iCodeID=@iCodeID,
                dDate=@dDate,
                nSale=@nSale,
                nCumdep=@nCumdep,
                nBookvalue=@nBookvalue,
                cRemarks=@cRemarks
            WHERE
                iDispID = @iDispID  
END
```